# format JSON value with a php function and print result inside a div#id

Tags: php, jquery

So far, I have got the following:

```
$.getJSON('getinfo.php', { id:id }, parseInfo);

function parseInfo(data) {
   $('div#info').fadeOut("fast", function() {
      $('div#info').html(data.desc);
   }
}
```

I am able to print the results (data.desc) inside the div#info html tag, but before I do so, I want to format data.desc with my php function. So, basically I want to do something like this,

```
function parseInfo(data) {
   $('div#info').fadeOut("fast", function() {
      <?php 
         $formated = some_php_function(data.desc);
      ?>  
      $('div#info').html(<?php echo $formated ?>);
   }
}
```

Comment: Wwhy don't you let the original script that returned the value `getinfo.php` - do that for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to call a PHP function in the middle of a Javascript function. You'll have to format this value before you send it through as a JSON value, or you'll have to duplicate your PHP function in Javascript and use it client-side.

Answer (score 0):

Like I say, why not do that formatting function within getinfo.php?

Another option would be to write a JavaScript function instead of a PHP one to format your variable. What sort of formatting do you need to do on it?

Comment: Thank you, Abs. I'll try out your first suggestion and format it within the getinfo.php. What the php function basically does is, searches the data.desc for something like the following <span> tags:
<span id="name.123" class="cite">some note</span> 
and then converts them into: 
<a class="link" href="http://www.mypage.com/page.php?ln=xxx#name">some note</a>, basically removing the 'name' in the <span id="name.123"...> and appending it to URL and then substituting the latter for the entire <span> tag.  
So, when the html(data.desc) is loaded, all the <span>...</span> shows up as a hyperlinks.